# Custom (Non-CiviCRM) MySQL Tables in SearchKit and Afform?

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder

I'm loving the features of SearchKit with Afform/Form Builder. Very powerful and straightforward to use so far.

We have several entities/tables in MySQL that we use in conjunction with Civi tables (joining to civicrm_contact, for example). So far, to bring these entities into the Civi GUI (as a contact summary tab) so people can create new records or view records, I've been creating Pages and Forms in our internal extension with civix. It seems like SearchKit/Afform would really speed up the development of those pages and even allow others on my team to build forms and search displays.

Is there a way we can have any SQL statement be a source for SearchKit and Form Builder, with ways to incorporate filters as where clauses?

If not, is there any other way I can get a custom table to be a source table for these tools, so we can bring them in and join them to other entities like Contacts?

These options of somehow allowing external tables into the tools would be a huge benefit to us and, I'm sure, other developers in the community.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating your tables using https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity then they should be automatically available like the built-in entities I would think.